# PowerShell script issue with system logs

Tags: powershell

The issue I am having is the first three lines. Once this is run the logs pull into a txt file but append a "..." after a certain number of characters instead of returning the entire line. Any ideas of how I can stop that?

```
Get-EventLog -Newest 1000 -LogName "Security" | Out-File -FilePath C:\SecurityLogs.txt
Get-EventLog -Newest 1000 -LogName "System" | Out-File -FilePath C:\SystemLogs.txt
Get-EventLog -Newest 1000 -LogName "Application" | Out-File -FilePath C:\ApplicationLogs.txt
Get-Item -Path C:\Windows\Prefetch\* | Out-File -FilePath C:\prefetch.txt
Get-Process -FileVersionInfo | Out-File -FilePath C:\processes.txt
```

Comment: `Out-File` has a `-Width` parameter. The default value is 80 characters, but you can set it to a higher value. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6#required-parameters)

Comment: You may want to use `Export-Csv` instead of ` Out-File`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the preformatted text of the command to the file. You can do something like this.

```
Get-EventLog -Newest 1000 -LogName "Security" | select * | out-file -FilePath C:\SecurityLogs.txt
```

This will expand every attribute.

This command `Get-EventLog -Newest 1000 -LogName "Security" | get-member` will show you all the attributes\properties you have access too for displaying.

You then can run something like:

```
Get-EventLog -Newest 1000 -LogName "Security | Select-Object index, timewritten, message | format-list`
```

You can play with `format-list`, `format-table` and other output commands to get the results you like.

There are other methods you can do also. What you want the end result to be would depend on what you use.

Comment: Great, just started using this site. Can you mark it as answered?